# Cargar Datos en Base de datos SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

Buenas noche Tengo una duda ¿Se puede cargar datos de access a sql server pero solamente cargar los datos que en la tabla de sql no existe?

Comment: si, por supuesto...

Comment: gbianchi está en lo correcto. Sí se puede. Espero haya sido de utilidad. Saludos! Por cierto, [en este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) podrás encontrar información importantísima que puede ayudarte a lograr tu objetivo.

Comment: Si, si se puede. Un saludo.

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda